# InvalidTemplateResourceException after move to new server

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i have a site package extension for my template in Typo3 9.5. Furthermore I have another extension for a specific purpose. Now this extension searches in the ProviderExtension for template files!?!? On my development machine everything works fine. After I have transferred everything to a remote server, this exception occurs on those pages where the plugin of the extension is included. Other pages work.

```
The Fluid template files enter code here
"/home/.sites/822/site4946398/web/bttemplate/public/typo3conf/ext/amtstafel/Resources/Private/Partials/Navigation/Top.html", 
"/home/.sites/822/site4946398/web/bttemplate/public/typo3conf/ext/amtstafel/Resources/Private/Partials/Navigation/Top" 
could not be loaded.
```

Here is the typoscript fom the Site-Template

```
page = PAGE
page {
    config.index_enable = 1
    typeNum = 0
    shortcutIcon = EXT:btbuerger2/Resources/Public/Icons/favicon.ico
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        templateName = TEXT
        templateName {
            cObject = TEXT
            cObject {
                data = pagelayout
                required = 1
                case = uppercamelcase
                split {
                    token = pagets__
                    cObjNum = 1
                    1.current = 1
                }
            }
            ifEmpty = Default
        }
        templateRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:btbuerger2/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:btbuerger2/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
        }
        layoutRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:btbuerger2/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
        }
...
```

The extension amtstafel has a static typoscript which is included in the Main-Template. Here templateRootPaths and layoutRootPaths is defined. As mentioned, the Extension was built with Extension-Builder and works fine so long..

```
plugin.tx_amtstafel_bulletinentry {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:{extension.shortExtensionKey}/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_amtstafel_bulletinentry.view.templateRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:tx_amtstafel/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_amtstafel_bulletinentry.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
```

"bttemplate" is the template extension, "amtstafel" is the additional extension.
In the place of .../amtstafe/... there is not need for partials ...

Thank you for help!
Thomas

Comment: You mention provider extension. That is a flux concept. Is it correct to assume that you use flux?

Comment: no, sorry, for the wording...  i meant a site-package, i do not use flux.

Comment: Can you please show the TypoScript for the main PAGE object? FLUIDTEMPLATE has probably wrong *RootPaths. This is just from guessing that this is a page rather than a content template (judging from Partials/Navigation)

Comment: i found out that all my extensionen built with extensionbuilder throw this error.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jonas Eberle, see the typoscript above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your constant `page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath` is set to `EXT:amtstafel/Resources/Private/Partials/`

This constant is used in your `page.10.templateRootPaths.1`